# volume of solid obtained by rotating the graph about $x=2$ line

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find the volume of solid generated by revolving the regin bounded by the graph of the equation $y=2x^2,y=0,x=2$ about $x=2$ line is

What i try

[image]

Put $x=2$ in $y=2x^2$ . We get $y=8$

So Volume of solid is

$$\pi\int^{8}_{0}r^2dy$$

I did not understand How can i find radius of generating cone in terms of $y$. Hp me please. Thanks

Comment: You need to find half of the width inside the parabola for any given height $y$. Rearrange your parabola equation for $x$ in terms of $y$ to find the radius in terms of $y$.

Comment: you mean we have to take $r=2-\sqrt{\frac{y}{2}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT...set $r=2-x$ and change $dy$ into $\frac{dy}{dx}dx$. Then you use $x$ values for the limits.